# Почему не работает $model->save() yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Контроллер

```
$companyObj = new Company();
           
$city = City::findOne(['name' => $post["CabinetRegistrationForm"]["city_name"]]);
            
$companyObj->name = $post["CabinetRegistrationForm"]["company_name"];
$companyObj->activity = 1;
$companyObj->district_id = $city->district_id;
$companyObj->region_id = $city->region_id;
$companyObj->municipality_id = $city->municipality_id;
$companyObj->city_id = $city->id;
$companyObj->address = $post["CabinetRegistrationForm"]["address"];
$companyObj->inn = $post["CabinetRegistrationForm"]["inn"];
$companyObj->approved = 0;
$companyObj->head_fio = $post["CabinetRegistrationForm"]["head_fio"];
$companyObj->phone = $post["CabinetRegistrationForm"]["phone"];
           
$companyObj->save();
```

Модель

```
namespace common\models;

use mdm\admin\models\AuthItem;
use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveQuery;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\db\Query;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "company".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $org_form
 * @property string $activity
 * @property int $district_id
 * @property int $region_id
 * @property int $municipality_id
 * @property int $city_id
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $inn
 * @property int $approved
 * @property string $head_fio
 * @property string $phone
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $site
 *
 * @property DistrictModel $district
 * @property Municipality $municipality
 * @property City $city
 * @property User[] $users
 * @property SchoolClass[] $classes
 */
class Company extends \common\components\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'company';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'org_form', 'activity'], 'required'],
            [['district_id', 'region_id', 'municipality_id', 'city_id', 'approved'], 'integer'],
            [['address'], 'string'],
            [['name', 'org_form', 'activity', 'inn', 'head_fio', 'email', 'site', 'presentation_url'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['phone'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['district_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => DistrictModel::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['district_id' => 'id']],
            [['municipality_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Municipality::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['municipality_id' => 'id']],
            [['presentation_url'], 'trim'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Name'),
            'org_form' => Yii::t('app', 'Org Form'),
            'activity' => Yii::t('app', 'Activity'),
            'district_id' => Yii::t('app', 'District ID'),
            'region_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Region ID'),
            'municipality_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Municipality ID'),
            'city_id' => Yii::t('app', 'City ID'),
            'address' => Yii::t('app', 'Address'),
            'inn' => Yii::t('app', 'Inn'),
            'approved' => Yii::t('app', 'Approved'),
            'head_fio' => Yii::t('app', 'Head Fio'),
            'phone' => Yii::t('app', 'Phone'),
            'email' => Yii::t('app', 'Email'),
            'site' => Yii::t('app', 'Site'),
            'presentation_url' => Yii::t('app', 'Presentation Url'),
        ];
    }
```

Вьюха

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup']); ?>

<div class="hidden">
<?= $form->field($model, 'role')->textInput() ?>
</div>
                
<?= $form->field($model, 'second_name')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->input('last_name') ?>      
<?= $form->field($model, 'email')->input('email') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'inn')->widget(SuggestionsWidget::class, [
      'token' => '*******************',
                    
]) ?>
               
                
<?php if ($model->role == RoleModel::ROLE_RESEARCH_COORDINATOR_OO): ?>                  
<?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->textarea(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'city_name')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'address')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'head_fio')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
..........
```

Вроде бы все правильно, никаких ошибок не выводится , `$companyObj->errors` - пустой массив, но `$companyObj->save` выдаёт false. В БД не появляется новая строка.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: ->load(), ->validate() может эти методы помогут найти ошибку?

Comment: @fedornabilkin $companyObj->save(false) работает, вставляет строку в базу, но абсолютно пустую данных нет , в чем дело подскажите?

Comment: Дело было в том что в модели у меня были public свойства одноимённые с полями БД. Из-за этого писались пустые строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри, когда ты вызываешь метод save(), сначала идет валидация модели по правилам которые ты в rules() описал, если все ок, модель полетела на сохранение в бд. Значит что ошибки валидации все-таки есть. Вызови метод $companyObj->validate() затем посмотри что тут $companyObj->getErrors(), ошибки будут, гарантирую)))

Валидацию кстати отключить можно при сохранении, $companyObj->save(false)

Переписал бы контроллер:

```js
        $model = new Company();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
```

И часть из контроллера в модель бы выкинул:

```js
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function beforeValidate(): bool
    {
        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

        $city = City::findOne(['name' => $post["CabinetRegistrationForm"]["city_name"]]);

        $this->activity = 1;
        $this->district_id = $city->district_id;
        $this->region_id = $city->region_id;
        $this->municipality_id = $city->municipality_id;
        $this->city_id = $city->id;
        $this->approved = 0;

        return parent::beforeValidate();
    }
```

Хотя этот твой поиск города исходя из данных формы, хз стремно как-то... По инкапсуляции тоже жестко) Бери да подставляй данные какие хочешь)

Запомни, в rules() описываешь только те поля которые есть в форме. Форма на 3 поля, в rules() 3 поля и описываешь, иначе все остальные аттрибуты подменить на любые можно будет))))

> А как из POST писать данные в модель правильно?

$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()):

- Загружаешь данные в модель из post
- Значения присвоятся только тем аттрибутам, которые описаны в rules(), все остальное будет проигнорировано.
- По поводу пачки hiddenInput() хз, как по мне они где-то на фоне у модели должны присваиваться, но раз уже так сделал, то нужно на них дополнительные валидаторы написать, чтобы ты был точно уверен, что никакой подмены не будет.

Comment: А как из POST писать данные в модель правильно?

Comment: @Dmitriy обновил